# What could be overriding UIButton attributes from viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, viewdidload

I load some defaults and set `UIButton` customizations in my `viewDidLoad` method. The defaults load fine. However, the `UIButtons` do not get their customization.

When I put the exact same `UIButton` code in an action button to trigger the customizations - it works great. I changed the button to "Custom" in the .xib.

I feel like something is happening out of order and that is why the buttons do not launch with their mods.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    lifeTotal.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bankKey"];
    floatTot = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"floatKey"];
    dollaInt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"intKey"];
    hourlyRate.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"rateKey"];
    rate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"rateInt"];

    NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.start, self.stop, self.fbButton, self.clearLifeTotal,nil];


    for(UIButton *btn in buttons)
    {
        // Set the button Text Color
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        // Set default backgrond color
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        // Round button corners
        CALayer *btnLayer = [btn layer];
        [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

        // Apply a 1 pixel, black border around Buy Button
        [btnLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [btnLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `[super viewDidLoad];` as the first line in your method?

Comment: Try putting the code in viewDidAppear instead.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Still not working!

Comment: Can you check if your loop is running? I mean control is going inside your loop?

Comment: Setting attributes in viewDidLoad should work fine.   Something else is going on.  How is the view controller loaded?

Comment: You can try removing and relinking your UIButtons to the xib?

Comment: This is what I did. Step 1. Added 4 buttons. Step 2. Set style of buttons to Custom. Step 3. Linked Button outlets to View Controller. Step 4. Added your code. Step 5. Execute the code, look at the customized buttons. Step 6. There is no step 6.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 Great Idea. Just tried but still doesnt work. I added code from my .h above if that helps

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on the line with `NSArray *buttons = …` and type `po self.start`, `po self.clearLifeTotal`, etc., what are the return values?  Also, is your XIB file linking the buttons to the instance variables you've declared or the @properties?

Comment: @BlackFlam3 Got it to work! Dragged the line from the (@)property line from the .h to the .xib worked better than from within the .xib.. Doesn't make sense to me but Ill take it! Thanks much

Comment: It happens sometimes, although I am unable to figure out why, and it invariably leads me to relinking the controls, and they start working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting [super viewDidLoad] at the top of the method, before your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your for loop with this and check :

```
    for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if (btn == self.start || btn == self.stop || btn == self.fbButton || btn == self.clearLifeTotal)
        {
            // Set the button Text Color
            [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

            // Set default backgrond color
            [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

            // Round button corners
            CALayer *btnLayer = [btn layer];
            [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

            // Apply a 1 pixel, black border around Buy Button
            [btnLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
            [btnLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that a quick look at `UIButton.h` shows that viewDidLoad is not exposed on a UIButton. It is, therefore, not being called.

You're looking for `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` or `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`.